# How to use CSS for formatting Crystal Report in Winform?

Tags: c#, css, winforms, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am using VS 2008 for a Winform. I have crystal reports in the project which I would like to format with the help of CSS.

Can anyone point me with the right tutorial to start this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystal Reports for Visual Studio has limited HTML formatting. see [This Forum Post](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3210329) (Google for [more](https://www.google.com/search?q=sap%20crystal%20reports%20HTML%20CSS%20suppoort&aq=f&oq=sap%20crystal%20reports%20HTML%20CSS%20suppoort&aqs=chrome.0.57.9204&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=es-419&q=sap%20crystal%20reports%20HTML%20CSS%20support&spell=1&sa=X&ei=8VkwUeCqBOigiQKd94H4Dg&ved=0CC0QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.cGE&fp=3a5fa108bc9fcfbb&biw=1920&bih=1091)).
I've been recently trying to make some formatting on my reports using HTML and saddly discovered that it doesn't even suport divs it is just for text formatting, and most CSS attributes are not supported. At the end I had to use RTF formatting (Just because I needed the Justify Paragraph option for Legal Letters).

Hope it help,

Answer (score -1):

CSS works only in web application. If you want to customize your windows app look and feel, you can use either XML file or resource file. Specify all of your control's settings into XML or res file and use this file at runtime when your window app form loads.

sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StylesSheetFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Styles>
        <Style Name="FormType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="BackColor" Value="White" />
                <Property Name="Text" Value="Personal information" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="DataGridType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor" 
                          Value="White" />
                <Property Name="AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor" 
                          Value="214,222,247" />
                <Property Name="Columns[0].HeaderText" 
                          Value="Color name" />
                <Property Name="Columns[1].HeaderText" Value="My rate" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="TabControlType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
                <Property Name="TabPages[0].BackColor" Value="White" />
                <Property Name="TabPages[1].BackColor" Value="White" />
                <Property Name="TabPages[2].BackColor" Value="White" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="LabelType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="TextAlign" Value="TopLeft" />
                <Property Name="BorderStyle" Value="None" />
                <Property Name="ForeColor" Value="72,94,158" />
                <Property Name="Font" 
                          Value="Microsoft Sans Serif,8.25pt,style=Regular" />
                <Property Name="Height" Value="20" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="LabelType2">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="ForeColor" Value="Red" />
                <Property Name="Font" 
                          Value="Microsoft Sans Serif,8.25pt,style=Bold" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="TextBoxType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="TextAlign" Value="Left" />
                <Property Name="BorderStyle" Value="Fixed3D" />
                <Property Name="Font" Value="Tahoma,10,style=Regular" />
                <Property Name="Height" Value="20" />
                <Property Name="Width" Value="200" />
                <Property Name="BackColor" Value="214, 222, 247" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="HyperLinkType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="BorderStyle" Value="None" />
                <Property Name="ForeColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Property Name="Font" 
                          Value="Tahoma,10,style=Italic,Underline" />
                <Property Name="Height" Value="30" />
                <Property Name="Width" Value="200" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="ButtonType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="TextAlign" Value="TopLeft" />
                <Property Name="ForeColor" Value="Black" />
                <Property Name="BackColor" Value="214;222;247" />
                <Property Name="Font" Value="Tahoma,8.25,style=Italic" />
                <Property Name="Height" Value="23" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="ComboBoxType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="BackColor" Value="White" />
                <Property Name="Font" Value="Tahoma,10,style=Italic" />
                <Property Name="Height" Value="30" />
                <Property Name="Width" Value="200" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
        <Style Name="RadioButtonType1">
            <Properties>
                <Property Name="ForeColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Property Name="Font" Value="Verdana,8,style=Regular" />
                <Property Name="Width" Value="150" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Value="true" />
            </Properties>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
</StylesSheetFile>
```

Comment: Where can I find .aspx page in Winforms? I hope you read the question Its not for WebForms but for Winforms

Comment: Yeah you cannot use CSS in a winforms app. You could embed a browser in the app and use css on the pages it displays but not on the actual controls.

You can get various libraries which let you control the rendering of the controls in your forms and then apply a skin to them. Be aware that this will increase the amount of memory and processing power you will need to run it.

If you were working in WPF then it would be a lot more suited to custom skins as this technology is built in.